# Secure some of the endpoints with Basic Auth and some with OAuth 2 in Spring Web flux

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, oauth-2.0, basic-authentication

I am trying to implement the configuration for securing some of the endpoints with basic auth and some with oauth 2.

I tried using pattern and it's not working properly. This is something that I tried. But, the endpoints configured for basic auth is also using Oauth now. I am new to spring security. Could someone help me here to figure out what's going wrong.

```
 @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/common/**", "/hystrix.stream", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger.html").permitAll()
            }.authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            }.authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority(ROLE_API_USER).and().httpBasic()
            }.authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/api/auth-protected/**").authenticated().and().oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            }
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().denyAll()
            .and()
            .build()
    }
```

Edit based on one of the answers:
I tried creating a second webfilter chain and now it redirects for oauth login for all the endpoints

```
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/common/**", "/hystrix.stream", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger.html").permitAll()
            }.authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic()
            }.authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority(ROLE_API_USER).and().httpBasic()
            }
            .authorizeExchange()
            .anyExchange().denyAll()
            .and()
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    fun springSecurityFilterChainWithOauth(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .authorizeExchange {
                it.pathMatchers("/api/auth-protected/**").authenticated().and().oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            }
            .build()
    }
```

Comment: Just copy everything and create a second webfilterchain and set the order. This gets asked every week

Comment: @Toerktumlare I tried that as well and gave 1st order for Oauth. But, all the requests now redirect to Oauth even the ones confgured without any authentication

Comment: Then you must have implemented things wrong but since you havnt posted anything its impossible for us to help you, good luck!

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have edited my question with the code for second webfilterchain. Could you please have a look and let me know what I am missing here or doing wrong?